# Can't succeed running kivy on windows 10

Tags: python, kivy

I've tried to install kivy on windows 10 and after I installed and also uninstalled and reinstalled again everything from the start, I am encountering this problem when trying to run the demo file or even the `"Hello world"` test:

```
   C:\Users\97252\tutorial_env\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/97252/Desktop/matan.py

   [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\97252\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-12-31_85.txt

   [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1

   [INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle_dev" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew_dev" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2_dev" 0.3.1

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\97252\tutorial_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\97252\tutorial_env\Scripts\python.exe"

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)

[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes

sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

  File "C:\Users\97252\tutorial_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

  File "C:\Users\97252\tutorial_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>

  from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can some one help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: error shows problem with `sdl2` - it is C/C++ library which you may have to install separatelly. See [SDL](http://libsdl.org/)

Comment: Hey, I managed to run the script by changing the project interpreter in pyCharm IDE. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest answering your own question and marking it as the accepted answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the script by changing the project interpreter in pyCharm IDE.